# Чтение jar-архива Java

Tags: classloader, java

Добрый день!
Я вроде бы очень простую вещь делаю, но вылезает непонятная ошибка. Пишу свой класслоудер, по примеру [link text](http://samolisov.blogspot.ru/2008/01/java.html)
вот код, который загружает классы из архива:

```
    private void cacheClasses() {
    try {
        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jarFileName,false);//<--------------
        Enumeration entries = jarFile.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry jarEntry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();
            if (match(normalize(jarEntry.getName()), packageName)) {
                byte[] classData = loadClassData(jarFile, jarEntry);
                if(classData != null){
                    Class<?> clazz = defineClass(stripClassName(normalize(jarEntry.getName())
                    ), classData, 0 , classData.length);
                    cache.put(clazz.getName(), clazz);
                    System.out.println("== class " + clazz.getName() + " loaded in cache");
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

При загрузке архива вылезает исключение, что файл не найден!
Но этого не может быть, потому что архив я положил в системное свойство *java.class.path*. При этом объект *new File(мойJar.jar)* может быть создан!

Comment: Засорять глобальную переменную *CLASSPATH* - не выход

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А при чем тут java.class.path? Работа с файлами обычно ведется в рабочей директории. Вот в нее и надо ложить jar-ник.

---

В [доке](docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) нет ни слова про classpath.

> При этом объект new File(мойJar.jar)

Само собой. Это же просто враппер к файловой системе. А вот `new File("мойJar.jar").exists()` вернет `false`.

**Обновление**

> рабочая директория - папка , где .class хранится?

Рабочая директория это директория, находясь в которой, вы запустили JVM (речь о командной строке).

Чтобы знать наверняка, какую директорию JVM считает рабочей, можете выполнить:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

> любое обращение к файлам, может искать файлы в classpath.

Classpath - универсальная переменная среды, по которой некоторые виды загрузчиков (classloader) ищут и загружают **классы**. Поэтому он назвается **class**path

Comment: @Nofate рабочая директория - папка , где .class хранится?

PS И вообще я считал, что classpath - универсальная переменная среды, любое обращение к файлам, может искать файлы в classpath.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Теперь ясно что делать, заставить класс лоудер искать классы в класс патх)